# Google Sheets Get The Value Matching Closest Date

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am working on Google Sheets and my data is Col A Date and Col B Item Name and Col C Item Rate.

I want to get item rate based on Item name but the rate should be nearest to a particular date entered by me. Check the below link of the sheet for better understanding.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16Zq-MFL0AMNRWpich2_woxwxxlciKPMOMrL_gfv1szE/edit#gid=0

Any help on above will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your question can be greatly improved if you add a table to the question. [Tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) are a better alternative than spreadsheets to show your data structure.  If you share spreadsheets, make sure to also add images of your sheet to avoid closure of your question, as questions here must be [self](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455/) [contained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149892). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), when you share Google files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try, using query, sort (desc) and index

```
=index(query(A:C,"select A,C where B='"&G2&"' and A<=DATE'"&TEXT(F2,"yyyy-MM-dd")&"' order by A desc limit 1",0),1,2)
```

edit, with arrayformula

```
=iferror(arrayformula(vlookup(G2:G&"~"&F2:F,
ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(sort({unique(filter(B2:B,B2:B<>"")),unique(filter(B2:B,B2:B<>"")),sequence(counta(unique(B2:B)),2,0,0);B2:B&"~"&A2:A,B2:B,A2:A,C2:C},2,1,3,1),
count(A2:A)+counta(unique(B2:B)),4)
,4,1)))
```

[image]

or with a space in place of 0

```
=iferror(arrayformula(vlookup(G2:G&"~"&F2:F,
ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(sort({unique(filter(B2:B,B2:B<>"")),unique(filter(B2:B,B2:B<>"")),sequence(counta(unique(B2:B)),1,0,0),transpose(split(REPT(" ,",counta(unique(B2:B))),","));B2:B&"~"&A2:A,B2:B,A2:A,C2:C},2,1,3,1),
count(A2:A)+counta(unique(B2:B)),4)
,4,1)))
```

[image]

Comment: @ Mike Thanks for the solution and it work fine, however, I need to copy paste the formula in every cell to get the result, is there any approach to use arrayformula so there is no need to apply the formula in every cell.

Comment: @ Mike Thanks for super quick marvellous solution, its working great and giving perfect solution as desired, except one situation E.g. If I select Item 2 and select the data as 3/12/21 then first formula using QUERY give error in result (this is correct) as the rates for Item 2 starts from 6/12/21 and the second formula picks the rates for Item A considering it as the nearest match.  This can be checked from row no. 5 of the sheet.

Comment: you are right, here is a correction, but I can't give #N/A, but I can replace it by 0

Comment: i added a second version with a space in front of N/A (it is possible ti do with 'Not Application' for instance)

Comment: @ Mike its really brilliant solution .. Bravo..... am giving thumbs-up to the answer, and I think this is really getting interesting, am sharing one situation in the sheet which requires further investigation. In the test case of the sheet I had applied the alternate formula in cell No. J2, you can see that there is no result in this case, but if I delete data from Cell A59 then column J will start giving result.

Comment: weird! I still can't figure out why this is happening. I added in L1 how to build the intermediate table on which I apply vlookup. Even after doing this, I still can't figure out why!

Comment: if I first build the intermediate array in L1, then apply the arrayformula/vlookup in R1, it works! (weird!)

Comment: I tested in different situations and intermediate array works...

Answer (score 0):

Just leaving an alternate approach here:

```
=map(F2:F,G2:G,lambda(f,g,if(f="",,let(Σ,ifna(filter(A:C,B:B=g,A:A<=f)),xlookup(f,index(Σ,,1),index(Σ,,3),,-1)))))
```

[image]