# Find closest date of matching value earlier than a given date in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I'm looking to find the closest matching earlier date for a given name and to be able to restrict the number of days.

For example, say john's value 3/30/23, and I want to find any occurence within 20 days of 3/20/23 but not later than that date, then the formula will try to find a match of name & date in A:A, B:B and return a date within a specified time period.

In the table below I will provide a name (C2) date (C3), and I might also give a limit of days (C4).

| Name | Date | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| john | 3/27/2023 | john |
| salley | 3/28/2023 | 3/30/2023 |
| john | 3/29/2023 | 20 |
| salley | 3/30/2023 | **formula** |
| john | 3/31/2023 |  |

The formula should return 3/29/2023 in C5.

My formula doesnt seem to be working and instead is returning the first match.

```
ArrayFormula(INDEX(B1:B, MATCH(MIN(IF((A1:A=C1)*(B1:B<=C2)*(C2-B1:B<=20), C2-B1:B, 999999)), 0)))
```

Comment: There are some similar questions I found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73154182/google-sheets-get-the-value-matching-closest-date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try:

```
=let(Σ,ifna(filter(B:B,A:A=C2,B:B<=C3,B:B>C3-20)),
        xlookup(C3,Σ,Σ,,-1))
```

[image]

Comment: please upvote questions if you like them.

Comment: Please See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75901018/find-closest-date-of-matching-date-an-array-in-google-sheets where question is asked based on this to adapt to an array.