# Find closest date of matching date an array in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I'm looking to find the closest matching earlier date for a given name that also restricts values and adapts the following formula which works on an [individual line level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75900002/find-closest-date-of-matching-value-earlier-than-a-given-date-in-google-sheets/75900103#75900103) to work if it was just pasted in E2.

```
let(Σ,ifna(filter(B:B,A:A=C2,B:B<=C3,B:B>C3-20)),
    xlookup(C3,Σ,Σ,,-1))
```

In the table below the values in D:E are used to look up and find corresponding values in A:B returning the nearest date that is not less than 20 days earlierin F:F. How can this be reproduced by simply placing one formula (array, map etc) in E2?

| name | earlier date |  | name | later date | **output** | formula text |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| john | 3/25/2023 |  | john | 3/25/2023 | **3/25/2023** | =let(Σ,ifna(filter(B:B,A:A=D3,B:B<=E3,B:B>E3-20)),xlookup(E3,Σ,Σ,,-1)) |
| salley | 3/26/2023 |  | salley | 3/26/2023 | 3/26/2023 | =let(Σ,ifna(filter(B:B,A:A=D4,B:B<=E4,B:B>E4-20)),xlookup(E4,Σ,Σ,,-1)) |
| john | 3/29/2023 |  | john | 3/27/2023 | 3/25/2023 | =let(Σ,ifna(filter(B:B,A:A=D5,B:B<=E5,B:B>E5-20)),xlookup(E5,Σ,Σ,,-1)) |
| salley | 3/30/2023 |  | salley | 3/28/2023 | 3/26/2023 | =let(Σ,ifna(filter(B:B,A:A=D6,B:B<=E6,B:B>E6-20)),xlookup(E6,Σ,Σ,,-1)) |
| john | 3/31/2023 |  | john | 3/29/2023 | 3/29/2023 | =let(Σ,ifna(filter(B:B,A:A=D7,B:B<=E7,B:B>E7-20)),xlookup(E7,Σ,Σ,,-1)) |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try:

```
=map(D2:D,E2:E,lambda(d,e,if(d="",,let(Σ,ifna(filter(B:B,A:A=d,B:B<=e,B:B>e-20)),xlookup(e,Σ,Σ,,-1)))))
```

[image]

Comment: how can equation be modified so that it is reversed (ie the closest date that is equal to or greater than 20? I tried =map(D2:D,E2:E,lambda(d,e,if(d="",,let(Σ,ifna(filter(B:B,A:A=d,B:B>=e,B:B<e+20)),xlookup(e,Σ,Σ,,-1)))))
but doesnt seem to work.

Comment: Also replace -1 with 1